# Codeigniter get selected values of form_multiselect

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm working on a codeigniter website and i need to use form_multiselect the select shows fine but when i post it and i try to get the selected value on the controller when i do :

`$category = $this->input->get_post('category');
var_dump($category);`

i get string(0) "".

here is my codes :

**View**

```
<?php echo form_multiselect('category[]', $categories); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
$data['categories'] = $this->blog_category_model->getblogcatDropDown($app_key);
$category = $this->input->get_post('category'); 
var_dump($category);
die;
```

**Model**

```
public function getblogcatDropDown($app_key)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `webapp_blog_categories` WHERE `app_key`=('.$this->db->escape($app_key).') ORDER BY `id` ASC')->result();
    $return[''] = 'Choose blog category';
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $return[$row->id] = $row->cat_name;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

**update**

when i use html select on the view :

```
<select multiple name="tst[]">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

it works fine , but the generated form not working

can any one help me ? thanks

Comment: did you check your database table for category field?

Comment: $category = $this->input->get_post('category',TRUE);

Comment: and also check how r u creating this $categories???

Comment: the select shows fine , i added the model code .

Comment: than test this:   $this->input->get_post('category',TRUE);

Comment: yes i tried  $this->input->get_post('category',TRUE); same result

Comment: print_r($data['categories']); test in controller show me result.

Comment: when i do  print_r($data['categories']); i get Array ( [] => Choose blog category [4] => category1 [5] => category2 )

Comment: $this->input->get_post('tst'); this should be this

Comment: tst it just for test and yes when i do $this->input->get_post('tst'); i get the selected valuse . but if i use form_multiselect() from form helper it not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104281/discussion-between-devpro-and-haffane-hatim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `form method="post"` and simply check the whether the value is posted when you submit the form using developer tools.

for getting the value in controller. it's simply.

> $category = $this->input->post('category');

Comment: did you check the posting using developer tools?

Comment: in Google Chrome, press F12, select Network tab, put a check on ```Preserve log``` then submit the form and check the post values.

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundarywlwKDTeyr7lnYVOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category[]"

4
------WebKitFormBoundarywlwKDTeyr7lnYVOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category[]"

5

Comment: as you can see the form is posted and the category contain values but it not working

Comment: Use $category = $this->input->post('category'); print_r($category); what output show on ?